# Adding a footer using perl

Tags: perl, header, footer

I have a small situation.  First of all, I have a list of split files.  Xaa through Xal.  My goal was to add a header and footer to each one.  I figured out how to add the header.  That part is done.  Now I just need to know how to insert the footer.  Any suggestions?  Here is the script.

```
open(M,"<","xak.txt");
@m = <M>;
close(M);
open(M,">","xak.txt");
print M "LINE: while (<>) {\n";
print M @m;
close(M);
```

This script perfectly added the header `LINE: while (<>) {\n`.  I am now trying to simply add

```
    print;
}
```

at the bottom of my file, or more so `\tprint;\n}`.  I feel like I am close but I just need to know the difference in adding something at the top of a file compared to the bottom.

Comment: That looks like Perl code you're trying to apply a hack to. Did you know that you can simply use the `-p` switch to accomplish what you want? In other words, the `-p` switch puts a `while(<>)` + `continue { print }` loop around your program, so for example `perl -p Xaa`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it after the array:

```
open(M,"<","xak.txt");
@m = <M>;
close(M);
open(M,">","xak.txt");
print M "LINE: while (<>) {\n";
print M @m;
print M "\tprint;\n}";
close(M);
```